# Hash table - why should hash function and compression function be separate?

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashtable, hash-function

I was wondering why there is a need to separate the hash function and compression function when using a hash table?

AFAIK, first the hash function computes the indexes, and the compression function is used to narrow them down. 
When the values are inserted into the array, isn't the compressed key (the index) then only thing that counts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your terminology correctly, the hash function should work for any size array, while the compression function is specific to the current size. So a hash function might return the same 32bit number, the compression will for example calculate the modulo of said number to know which array index to use. Since most implementations of a hashtable shrink and grow dynamically when the table changes, it makes sense to separate the two.